# What is $f(n)$ in $NTIME(n)\subseteq DTIME(f(n))$ if $CIRCUITSAT$ is in $P$?

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, nondeterminism, polynomial-time, circuits

If [$CIRCUITSAT$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circuit_satisfiability_problem) in $n$ variables and $m$ gates has an $O((nm)^c)$ algorithm for a fixed $c>0$ then $NTIME(n)\subseteq DTIME(O(f(n)))$ for large enough $f(n)$. What is the smallest $f(n)$ in $NTIME(n)\subseteq DTIME(O(f(n)))$?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure on this, but I believe that the best known bound on this comes from the construction used for the best known bound on creating oblivious Turing machines. See [this Gödel's Lost Letter blog post](https://rjlipton.wordpress.com/2009/07/28/oblivious-turing-machines-and-a-crock/) on the relationship between circuit size and oblivious Turing machines, and in particular the "Open Problems" section.

Given an arbitrary deterministic Turing machine that runs in time $T(n)$, it is known how to construct an oblivious deterministic Turing machine that accepts the same language in time $O(T(n) \log T(n))$. I *believe* that this implies $\operatorname{NTIME}(t) \subseteq \operatorname{DTIME}(t^{2d} \log t)$, where $d$ is the CIRCUIT-SAT exponent from the question (the 2 coming from the fact that you wrote $(nm)^d$ instead of $(n + m)^d$). However, I have not verified the details myself.